# Python Django Progress Bar django-progressbarupload

Tags: javascript, python, django, django-forms, django-templates

I am trying to use this module 'django-progressbarupload' ( https://github.com/ouhouhsami/django-progressbarupload ). I've followed the installation instructions from the github page to the Letter but cannot get an upload bar in either Chrome or Firefox.

The instructions are pretty simple for setting up the settings.py file, I setup my admin.py like this:

```
## For the Model Admins for the File Upload classes ( Video and Audio )
from django.contrib import admin

## Get the forms
from django import forms

## Import the file models
from models import VideoFile
from models import AudioFile

## For the progress bar
class UploadAudioFileModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = AudioFile
class UploadVideoFileModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = VideoFile

## For the progress bar
class UploadAudioFileModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    change_form_template = 'progressbarupload/change_form.html'
    add_form_template = 'progressbarupload/change_form.html'
    form = UploadAudioFileModelForm
    class Media:
        js = ("http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js",)
## For the progress bar
class UploadVideoFileModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    change_form_template = 'progressbarupload/change_form.html'
    add_form_template = 'progressbarupload/change_form.html'
    form = UploadAudioFileModelForm
    class Media:
        js = ("http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js",)

admin.site.register(VideoFile, UploadVideoFileModelAdmin)
admin.site.register(AudioFile, UploadAudioFileModelAdmin)
```

Here is my upload template:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% load progress_bar %}

{% block title %}Upload your !{% endblock %}

{% block content %}

<h1>Upload Information -</h1>

        {% if form.errors %}
        <p class="error">
                Please correct the error{{ form.errors|pluralize }} below.
        </p>
        {% endif %}

        <script type="text/javascript" src="../media/js/jquery.formset.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
           $(function() {
               $('#upload_formset ul').formset({
                        addText: 'Add a new Stop',
                        deleteText: 'Remove this Stop'
                });
           })
        </script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../media/js/progress_bar.js"></script>

        <form id="upload_formset" action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data"> {% csrf_token %}
                <table>
                {{ form.as_table }}
                </table>
        <br><br/>

        <table>
        {{ formset.management_form }}
        {% for forms in formset.forms %}
                <ul>
                {{ forms.as_p }}
                </ul>
        {% endfor %}

        </table>

        <br><br/>

        {% progress_bar %}

        <input type="submit" value="Submit!">

        </form>

{% endblock %}
```

Here is my base.html:

```
{% load static %}
{% load progress_bar %}

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN">
<html lang="en">

<head>

        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static "css/base_style.css" %}">
        <title>{% block title %}Welcome!{% endblock %}</title>
        {% block additional_head_info %}{% endblock %}

        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

        <h1>Welcome to the Website!</h1>

        {% if not user.is_authenticated %}
        <a href="/accounts/login/?next=/">login</a> | <a href="/accounts/register/">register</a> | <a href="/">home</a>
        {% endif %}

        {% if user.is_authenticated %}
        <a href="/accounts/logout/?next=/">logout</a> | <a href="/">home</a> | <a href="/upload/">upload</a>
        {% endif %}

        {% block content_title %}{% endblock %}
        {% block content %}{% endblock %}
        {% block footer %}

        <hr>
        <img src="{% static "img/debian-logo.png" %}" alt="Tours Logo"/>
        <p>Thanks for visiting - more content coming soon....</p>
        {% endblock %}

</body>

</html>
```

Here is the source for my webpage after Django renders it:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN">
<html lang="en">
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/css/base_style.css">
<title>Upload your !</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Welcome to the '' Website!</h1>
<a href="/accounts/logout/?next=/">logout</a> | <a href="/">home</a> | <a href="/upload/">upload</a>
<h1>Upload Information -</h1>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../media/js/jquery.formset.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
$('#upload_formset ul').formset({
addText: 'Add a new Stop',
deleteText: 'Remove this Stop'
});
})
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../media/js/progress_bar.js"></script>
<form id="upload_formset" action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data"> <input type='hidden' name='csrfmiddlewaretoken' value='O6NmPrifvScHP9IUXJIdaf0wnlrGFQgU' />
<table>
<tr><th><label for="id_name"> Name:</label></th><td><input id="id_name" maxlength="100" name="name" type="text" /><br /><span class="helptext">My Awesome </span></td></tr>
<tr><th><label for="id_contact_email">Contact Email:</label></th><td><input id="id_contact_email" name="contact_email" type="text" /><br /><span class="helptext">John.Appleseed@gmail.com</span></td></tr>
<tr><th><label for="id_description"> Description:</label></th><td><textarea cols="40" id="id_description" name="description" rows="10">
</textarea></td></tr>
<tr><th><label for="id_website">Website:</label></th><td><textarea cols="40" id="id_website" name="website" rows="1">
</textarea><br /><span class="helptext">e.g. http://www.ptrackapp.com</span></td></tr>
<tr><th><label for="id_address">Address:</label></th><td><textarea cols="40" id="id_address" name="address" rows="1">
</textarea><br /><span class="helptext">e.g. 1234 Colorado Ave. Denver, Colorado 80201</span></td></tr>
</table>
<br><br/>
<table>
<input id="id_form-TOTAL_FORMS" name="form-TOTAL_FORMS" type="hidden" value="2" /><input id="id_form-INITIAL_FORMS" name="form-INITIAL_FORMS" type="hidden" value="0" /><input id="id_form-MAX_NUM_FORMS" name="form-MAX_NUM_FORMS" type="hidden" value="1000" />
<ul>
<p><label for="id_form-0-address"> Step:</label> <textarea cols="40" id="id_form-0-address" name="form-0-address" rows="1">
</textarea> <span class="helptext">Enter an Address for this  Stop</span></p>
<p><label for="id_form-0-description"> Step Description:</label> <input id="id_form-0-description" maxlength="250" name="form-0-description" type="text" /> <span class="helptext">Enter some Information about this Stop</span></p>
<p><label for="id_form-0-video"> Step Video File:</label> <input id="id_form-0-video" name="form-0-video" type="file" /> <span class="helptext">max. 42 megabytes</span></p>
<p><label for="id_form-0-audio"> Step Audio File:</label> <input id="id_form-0-audio" name="form-0-audio" type="file" /> <span class="helptext">max. 42 megabytes</span></p>
</ul>
<ul>
<p><label for="id_form-1-address"> Step:</label> <textarea cols="40" id="id_form-1-address" name="form-1-address" rows="1">
</textarea> <span class="helptext">Enter an Address for this  Stop</span></p>
<p><label for="id_form-1-description"> Step Description:</label> <input id="id_form-1-description" maxlength="250" name="form-1-description" type="text" /> <span class="helptext">Enter some Information about this Stop</span></p>
<p><label for="id_form-1-video"> Step Video File:</label> <input id="id_form-1-video" name="form-1-video" type="file" /> <span class="helptext">max. 42 megabytes</span></p>
<p><label for="id_form-1-audio"> Step Audio File:</label> <input id="id_form-1-audio" name="form-1-audio" type="file" /> <span class="helptext">max. 42 megabytes</span></p>
</ul>
</table>
<br><br/>
<progress id="progressBar" data-progress_bar_uuid="131a107d-49ac-4e30-b307-5097dd13e232" value="0" max="100" hidden></progress><script>upload_progress_url = "/progressbarupload/upload_progress"</script>
<input type="submit" value="Submit!">
</form>
<hr>
<img src="/static/img/debian-logo.png" alt=" Logo"/>
<p>Thanks for visiting - more content coming soon....</p>
</body>
</html>
```

The page loads and I can upload my files just fine, but I never see a progress bar. I also do not see any errors in FireBug for loading of any scripts... Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Are the progress bar javascript files actually loading?

Comment: I do not see any errors in firebug or chrome's 'inspect field' tools. So I am assuming they are.

Answer (score 1):

There is some sort of 'issue' with the django-progressbarupload, check here https://github.com/ouhouhsami/django-progressbarupload/issues/2 . If you use Chrome, the progress will show up in the Chrome upload bar (check bottom left of the screen).